# Share database between local psql and docker compose postgres container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I need some advice on how to share a Postgres database between local psql and docker compose Postgres container.

I'm on a Debian-based Linux distro called Mint;
stack is Django 3.2 and Postgresql 12

I have a compose file with a Docker volume and local driver:

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  db_data:
    name: db_data
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgis/postgis:12-3.1
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - "./.env"

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server/
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - "./.env"
```

Both container are running properly but my local psql doesn't see any database I created or modified:

- when I run `docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres` I see my database
- but locally impossible to link with those data
- when I run `docker-compose ps`:

  ```
      Name           Command        State                    Ports                  
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  db       docker-entrypoint.sh postg ...   Up 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp
  server   /bin/sh -c python3 manage. ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp,:::8000->8000/tcp
  ```
- inside the volume db there is a whole postgres lib and bin package which is not the same that my local as i expect

I went through a lot of threads and tutorial and I worked around:

- container networks with network_mode :'host but didn't work
- ip addresses mapping
- changing dependencies of containers to depends_on: - db
- ...

I'm not that experienced, and if you could provide a workaround it would be amazing.

Comment: Since you have `ports: ['5432:5432']`, you should be able to connect to the database from the host normally, using `psql` or another client, as `localhost:5432`, without `docker exec`.  Does it work?

Comment: no it doesn't work with psql -U postgres or with -h localhost option. this is the main subject of this post. thanks for your answer. this is my first post maybe i could have wright better description.

Comment: What is your host OS?  If you check `docker-compose ps`, does the database start up?

Comment: my os is linux mint base on Ubuntu 20.04 focal. as i edited, both containers are showing when i run docker-compose ps

Comment: @justADev Would you mind adding to the description, a sample of the error when you try to connect to the database?

Comment: there is no error when conecting to psql locally , no error throught the container. data are missing locally and this is my issue.